# What method to use to stop scrolling of a chart?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I was looking through the methods of the chartXY of LightningChartJs and I can't seem to find a method to pause the scroll.I would like to know a method to play (continue) the scroll.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pause the scrolling by calling the [Axis.stop() method](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/classes/axis.html#stop).

You can then continue the scrolling by calling the [Axis.release() method](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/classes/axis.html#release). This will scroll the view to the latest added value that was added, while the scrolling was paused.

```
// Cache the default X axis for this example
const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()

// Stop the axis from scrolling after 5 seconds
setTimeout(() => axisX.stop(), 5000)
// Release the axis after 6 seconds
setTimeout(() => axisX.release(), 6000 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much any update on the release of version two?